# Database design to store values and arguments of functions

Tags: symfony, database-design, tree, conditional-statements, relational-database

I'm facing the following problem, where I need to design a filter engine with nested conditional logic.

I'm representing the logic as a tree where each branch first value is "OR" or "AND"; the second value can either be

- a name of a function
- another branch with further conditional structure

For example:

```
$tree = [
  'nodetype' => 'ruleset',
  'conditional' => 'OR',
  'children' => [
    [
      'nodetype' => 'method',
      'methodName' => 'startsWith'
      'arguments' => [
        'startsWithThis' => 'john',
        'subject' => 'john doe'
      ]
    ],
    [
      'nodetype' => 'ruleset'
      'conditional' => 'AND',
      'children' => [
        ...more nesting
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

This tree is then recursively evaluated using Symfony's Expression language component (I've registered custom expressions for methods like `startsWith` etc).

The issue is that methods will differ from one another in their number of arguments they accept and the order of those arguments. I'm not sure how to store this in a relational database, without serialising the whole tree to a json string; which I'd like to avoid.

What I came up with so far is the following database structure:

filters:

- id
- name

filter_arguments:

- id
- filter_id
- name

filter_usecases:

- id
- filter_id

filter_usecase_values

- id
- filter_usecase_id
- filter_argument_id
- value

However this table design does not address the issue of storing the "OR" / "AND" nature of a branch; and it also cannot represent nested filters (e.g. parent-child relation of branches).

How do I go about this? Is there a specific term that describes what I'm trying to achieve here? I'd gladly read more about this but I don't even know what to google.

Comment: You may find [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) on hierarchical data useful.

Answer (score 1):

To take a quick stab at it, going just from the data:

node

- id
- nodetype
- conditional
- method_name

children

- id
- parent_node_id
- child_node_id

arguments

- id
- node_id
- key
- value

Note that the relationships (children) and argument data are not in the node table, but rather are specified by cross reference tables you will have to join with when you retrieve nodes.  I would expect that it is the "children" table which will become the central actor in your recursing the tree, while "node" and "arguments" will be the joined tables.

Please let us know the solution you end up using successfully.